# Uneven shape of circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

How I can draw this Venn diagram of circles:

[image]

For your information i have tried it so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
\node[circle,draw,text=white,fill=gray,radius=10pt,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=25pt] (c) at (0,0){$Circle$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\fill[yellow!80!black, closed, tension=20] (0,0) .. (0,2) .. (5,5) .. (8,5) .. (7,-1);
\node[white, font=\bf\huge, rotate=10] at (4.5,3.5) {NLP};
\node[white, font=\bf, rotate=10] at (4.5,3) {Natural Language Processing};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Brown blob with white text]